# Queries run against MySql through sqlalchemy are much slower than on DB console

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a gigantic amount of SQL code that I am running against our database.  In order to make it readable, I have structured it as a massive number of temporary tables, which are created each time a query needs to be run.

When testing these queries, I run them in Sequel Pro against the DB, and while not fast, it takes about a minute to run.

I then take those same queries (most of which just say CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x (INDEX(blah)) AS (SELECT somecrazystuff); ) and run them in a python script through sqlalchemy, and they take closer to 15-20 minutes.

I have no idea why this could be happening, but it makes it awkward to test using the python script, and I end up doing most of my dev work in Sequel Pro and saving it later.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First idea: cut sqlalchemy out of the picture and try just running the query through mysql-python. SQLAlchemy is mostly useful for *constructing* SQL statements, which it then flushes through mysql-python; since you're constructing them by hand, get rid of the possible source of overhead.

The second one is to look at what the MySQL server is doing. Depending on what engine it's using, you could either dump all of the queries to logfiles (see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/)
or if you're using InnoDB tables, `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. You want to make sure that the queries are in fact identical when they hit the server coming from SQLAlchemy and from Sequel Pro.